# What is the differences between using SDL_bgi and libXbgi library?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, bgi

From [this link](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/) I came to know about using **graphics.h** using **SDL_bgi** & **libXbgi** library. But I don't know the diffrences between using **SDL_bgi** and **libXbgi** library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDL_bgi is multiplatform, faster, and more compatible with the original GRAPHICS.H by Borland; besides, it provides lots of extensions. No contest.